# UnitAmoutDecimal in Stripe not converted well in AED currency by using .Net

Tags: .net, stripe-payments

I send the price in decimal to Stripe the ammout is 22.3 AED but is appear like 0.223 AED
why that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by multiply the price by 100 becaue Stripe take the lower type of currency you sent..